# What's the difference between H(m) $\oplus$ H(key) and H(m || key) in MAC construction?

Tags: hash, authentication, hmac, provable-security, xor

We all know that HMAC has the form of $H(ikey || H(okey || M))$. I'm wondering what if we replace the H(okey || M) into H(okey) $\oplus$ H(M)? In other words, is $$H\Big( ikey \mathbin\| \big( H(okey) \oplus H(M)\big)\Big)$$ also as secure as HMAC? How does this transformation will affect the security of MAC?

I have learned about Bellare's original proof of NMAC and HMAC.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Fixed now and thanks @kelalaka! It should be $H(ikey || H(okey) \oplus H(M))$. For your question, $\oplus$ is the first operation applied. The message will be hashed and xored with the $H(okey)$, then the xor result will be concatenated with ikey. Finally, the whole string will be hashed together. Sorry for not stating this clear.

Comment: I've edited, please check!

Comment: Hint: if $H$ turns out to not be collision-resistant (like what happened to MD5 and SHA-1), what attack can you mount on $H(\text{okey}\mathbin\|( H(\text{ikey}) \oplus H(M)))$? Does that attack work on $H(\text{okey}\mathbin\|H(\text{ikey}\mathbin\|M))$ ? Note: my formulas are a step closer to HMAC than what's in the question. It's still not told how $\text{ikey}$ and $\text{okey}$ are built from an arbitrary key, and the two cases there are for that.

Comment: Thanks! Much clearer!

Comment: @fgrieu could you turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: If H is not collision-resistance, then the adversary can search an $ikey'$ which is different from $ikey'$ but H(ikey') = H(ikey). Therefore, My transformation would be vulnerable. However, if H is a collision-resistant hash function, then how can I evaluate its security? Thanks.